# How to resize UIImage vector graphic

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, vector-graphics

This is a rather strange question. You're probably thinking "You must resize the `UIImageView`, not the `UIImage`", but I can't get it working, and I'm not sure it's correct in this case.

I have a .pdf vector image I want to use in an iOS application. This vector image was exported to `.pdf` with the default size of **320 width**. Of course, this is vector, so it should scale perfectly.

When I create an `UIImageView` using that image (`UIImageView(image: vectorImage)`) it always gets a width of **320** (or scaled @2x/@3x).

I have constrained the `UIImageView` to have margin 0 left and right. On iPhone 5, this displays correctly, since it's a 320-based size screen. However, on iPhone 6 - the resolution is different, with a 375-based screen width.
Even though the imageView is constrained to the full width (375), the `UIImage` within still has a size of 320.
I never set the height.
To clarify, I'm using `ScaleAspectFit`. This should not cause the image to be stuck at 320 though. As I never set the height of the `UIImageView`, it should begin with a correct fit.

I can probably solve this if I have the aspect ratio for the image, but that seems unnecessary!

A correct result would be for the image to fill the entire width of the imageView, and the height of the imageView to change to fit the image.
The actual result is that the height and width of the `UIImage` is the same for all devices (relatively), and the height for the `UIImageView` is the same for all devices. Due to the constraints added, the width of the `UIImageView` is different, but the `UIImage` within is not changed. Why not?
I suspect that **if** the vector-image had been exported with a different default size, the result would be different. Why is this?

Comment: You cannot resize a UIImage and make it bigger. But you could render the PDF to a higher resolution though.

Comment: So the 'vector' is actually rasterized after launch? The vector-logic is only used to generate the @ 2x, @ 3x etc?

Comment: yay. It is rasterized after launch. Maybe this blog will help you http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/

Answer (score 1):

This post gets a lot of views so maybe worth a quick answer in case it helps anyone.

When using vectors you can't set the image and to the `UIImageView` and expect it to work out its height from the width, even when setting it to `ScaleAspectFit`.

One way to resolve this is to get the `UIImage`, get it's size and then use this to set the `UIImageView` height constraint.

For example:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "name")!
let ratio = image.size.height / image.size.width

imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: ratio).isActive = true
```